# Send email to custom user field on change, in JIRA issue tracker?

Tags: notifications, jira, issue-tracking

We have custom user fields (ie 'Business Analyst', 'Developer', etc.) in JIRA, and we would like to be able to send an email to those users when they are assigned to one of those fields.  I have looked over the [JIRA wiki](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+Notification+Scheme), and could not find a way to do this.

I know this is possible with the 'Issue Assigned' event, but in this case, the JIRA is not being assigned, since we are using custom fields.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: You can send notifications to the users in those custom fields. Notification Scheme, select an event, add the User Custom Field.

Comment: That will allow me to send an email to a custom field, but can I send an email to that field automatically when its value changes?

Comment: After scowering JIRA some more, I was not able to find a way to do this.

Comment: You could have that field only appear on a transition screen, so a user has to click on an action to edit it. The transition can send an event that can send email in turn.

Comment: Yeah, but in my case the person assigned isn't always known during a transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the JIRA Scripting Suite plugin --- you can easily do something like that, and in fact, they provide a sample script that shows you how to send a custom email (https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JSS/Scripting+Samples).

But you do have to catch two use cases --- as a post-function to a workflow transition and as a plain edit.  This plugin allows you to do both of those.  I typically just worry about handling those things at the point in the workflow in which those fields are required for the first time, and handle it in a post-function.

This plugin completely changed the power of JIRA for me.  I can quickly change scripts on the fly without recompiling or restarting JIRA.  You must check it out.

Comment: The plugin is now available on Atlassian Marketplace at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss . However, I could not find the documentation...

Answer (score 2):

This plugin: **[Email This Issue](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/4977?versionId=324116)** should be what you are looking for (sending email to custom fields).

> Email an issue from JIRA to arbitrary recipients - This plugin
>   [addresses this feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-5959) fulfilling considerable amount
>   (currently 30) of user votes.
>
> The plugin contains an issue operation component that allows users to
>   compose an email and send the issue to arbitrary recipients.
>
> Most important features are:
>
> 1. send email with issue details to email addresses outside  
>      JIRA,
>          assignee, reporter and watchers.
> 2. attach issue attachments to email
> 3. control who can invoke the operation
>      through a project   role
> 4. text and html email format are
>      supported, email body   understands
>          Confluence wiki markup
> 5. email template can be customized per project and issue   type
> 6. a comment is created
>      reflecting the event of sending an email
>          (body, recipients, etc) - see below
> 7. i18n-enabled, the plugin can be translated, it is currently
>          available in    **English, German, French, Polish, Italian and   Hungarian**.
> 8. you have options like "CC to me"
>      and "Reply to
>          me" to receive   a copy of the email or to receive replies to
>          the email.
> 9. < li>email recipients are added to watchers on   demand
> 10. recipients from custom fields and
>       groups/project roles can be   added
> 11. email options may be
>       reused, i.e. there is no need to check   all
>           your options every time you send an email
> 12. configure default values for email options via configuration   file